Graceful shutdown Spring Boot virtual thread
Spring Boot offers graceful shutdown but only for container(Tomcat). Since I also want my tasks are graceful shutdown, I set up my ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to:
// Initialize ThreadPoolTaskExecutor
threadPoolTaskExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);

When upgrading to Java 21, it supports virtual thread, so thread pool is no more necessary, I used SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor instead. Unfortunately SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor does not support graceful shutdown, I changed to this SimpleAsyncTaskScheduler with:
// Initialize SimpleAsyncTaskScheduler
simpleAsyncTaskScheduler.setTaskTerminationTimeout(600000);

The problem is:
This scheduler variant does not track the actual completion of tasks but rather just the hand-off to an execution thread

So when I shutdown my application, there are still running tasks that are NOT waited to complete, which is not really graceful.
How can I resolve this ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78321407/23297027
I think this could be a solution

no, it doesn't work
